# Connection between edges and nodes in a tree

Tags: graph, tree

I am new to competitive programming and I have come across a problem statement, which I am finding difficult to understand.It goes like this;

***The strength of an edge is determined by the number of pair of nodes which are connected with the help of that particular edge.
Alternatively, consider all the paths between every pair of nodes and the strength of an edge will be equal to the number of paths in which that edge comes.***

Can anyone help me with understanding what is it trying to say? I have tried more than a few times but I am unable to comprehend.

**P.S. I do not want its solution nor its code. I just need a little help with understanding the problem statement.**

Answer (score 0):

It means if lots of shortest paths go through a node its importatnt because of "betweenness". betweenness of an edge is proportional to the number of shortest paths go through it. it importatnt in lots of cases. for instance, if an edge has high betweenness score, it could be bridge(or local bridge) and if we cut that edge, graph becomes disconnected or average length of shoretest paths increase. [betweenness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality)
[bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory))

Answer (score 0):

By strength of an edge it means that how many pair of nodes this edge connects. Lets take an example(all edges are bidirectional)-

[Click here for example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDGJL.jpg)

for the edge 2-3, it's strength will be the number of pairs of nodes it connects.
lets count all pairs-

1. 2,3
2. 2,4
3. 2,5
4. 2,6
5. 1,3
6. 1,4
7. 1,5
8. 1,6

there are 8 pairs of nodes that edge 2-3 connects. So, it's strength is 8.

Alternatively, let's take all paths between all pairs of nodes.

1. 1-2
2. 1-2-3
3. 1-2-3-4
4. 1-2-3-4-5
5. 1-2-3-6
6. 2-3
7. 2-3-4
8. 2-3-4-5
9. 2-3-6
10. 3-4
11. 3-4-5
12. 3-6
13. 4-5
14. 4-6
15. 5-6

2-3 edge comes in 8 of them. So, the strength of edge 2-3 is 8.

Hope this makes it clear.